# Matlab GUI table - index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have created a Matlab GUI with Matlab's GUIDE tool and am executing some code now. As part of the output, I created a table, which I would like to populate with a matrix I calculated previously. I am continuing to run in the "index exceeds matric dimensions" problem and I don't understand why...

here is what my output matrix looks like that I want to pass in the output table:

```
Final =

                 22518                     21839
     0.539035438316014         0.563853656302944
     0.452748911981526         0.428133156280049
   0.00821564970246025       0.00801318741700627
    -0.452748911981526        -0.428133156280049
```

To me, this looks like a 5 x 2 matrix.

Here are the properties of the output table

```
Table (result) with properties:

            Data: {5x2 cell}
     ColumnWidth: {'auto'  'auto'}
  ColumnEditable: [0 0]
CellEditCallback: ''
        Position: [4.6 23.0769230769231 81.4 11.2307692307692]
           Units: 'characters'
```

In the property manager, it tells me that it has a Data structure of 5x2 cell array. The tag of the table is "result".

I now want to use the following code to populate the table:

```
set(handles.result('Data',Final))
```

However I keep getting the "index exceedsmatrix dimensions" error.

If I mannualy insert code to create a UI table it works fine:

```
h = uitable('Data', Final);
```

I noticed however, when I call the properties of this table, the data structure is different in the sense that is says "5x2 double" instead of "5x2 cell". Is this the error?

Would very much appreciate if someone could help me out here

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. There is a syntax error in your code. Instead of:

```
set(handles.result('Data',Final))
```

you should write:

```
set(handles.result,'Data',Final)
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple! Thanks a lot!